# Structs and Double Pointers Insides Other Structs, Multi-layer Confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

So I have three Structs with functions to go along with them...

```
struct Song{
    std::string songTitle;
    std::string songLength;
};
Song* createSong(string title, string length);
void displaySong(Song* s);
void destroySong(Song* s);

struct CD{
    std::string cdArtist;
    std::string cdTitle;
    int cdYear;
    int cdRate;
    int cdNumSongs;
    Song** songs;
};
CD* createCD(std::string artist, std::string title, int year, int rate, int numSongs);
void displayCD(CD* c);
void destroyCD(CD* c);
void addSong(CD* cd, std::string title, std::string length);

struct CDs{
    CD** cdArray;
    int cdMaxSize=1000;
    int cdCurrentSize=0;
};
CDs* createCDs (const char* filename);
void displayCDs (CDs* c);
void destoryCDs (CDs* c);
```

I have created and tested struct Song's functions as well as struct CD's functions. However I am having trouble implementing CDs* createCDs (const char* filename) which takes in things from a file and creates a dynamically stored array out of those CDs.

This is my code so far, I checked for dangling pointers and when my code compiles, it does so fine. Its just when ran, it stops for a few seconds and exits. Reading in the data from the text file has also been tested and that part works by itself.

Code so far...

```
CDs* createCDs(const char* filename){
    CDs* cds = new CDs;
    ifstream inFile(filename);

    CD* tempcd;
    CD** tempcdArray = new CD*[cds->cdCurrentSize];
    CD** tempcdNewArray;

    string tempArtist, tempTitle, tempSongTitle, tempSongLength;
    int tempYear, tempRate, tempNumSongs;

    while(getline(inFile, tempTitle)){ // WHEN IT GRABS NOTHING
        cds->cdMaxSize++;
        tempcdNewArray = new CD*[cds->cdMaxSize];
        for(int i=0; i<cds->cdCurrentSize; i++){
            tempcdNewArray[i] = tempcdArray[i];
            delete[] tempcdArray;
        }

        getline(inFile, tempArtist);
        inFile>>tempYear;
        inFile>>tempRate;
        inFile>>tempNumSongs;
        inFile.ignore();
        tempcd = createCD(tempArtist, tempTitle, tempYear, tempRate, tempNumSongs);
        for(int i=0; i<tempNumSongs; i++){
            getline(inFile, tempSongLength, ',');
            getline(inFile, tempSongTitle);
            addSong(tempcd, tempSongTitle, tempSongLength);
        }

        tempcdNewArray[cds->cdCurrentSize] = tempcd;
        tempcdArray = new CD*[cds->cdMaxSize];
        for(int i=0; i<cds->cdMaxSize; i++){
            tempcdArray[i] = tempcdNewArray[i];
            delete tempcdNewArray;
        }
        delete[] tempcd;
        cds->cdCurrentSize++;

    }
    for(int i=0; i<cds->cdCurrentSize; i++){
        cds->cdArray[i] = tempcdArray[i];
    }
    inFile.close();
    return cds;
}
```

In case you need to know, 
The one cd in the text file's layout is..

```
Eternal Tears of Sorrow (cd title)
Saivon Lapsi (cd artist)
2013 (cd year)
7 (cd rating)
13 (number of songs)
1:10,Saivo (length, title)
... (other songs after here)
```

I tried tracing my code for dangling pointers, I made sure I 'new' all sections of memory I am returning.. etc etc..

Comment: Why do you have to `new` everything? Just return by value instead of by pointer.

Comment: Is there a requirement not to use a proper container? A couple `std::vector`s on top of the other suggestion to use objects instead of pointers will simplify this dramatically. It will also prevent leaking memory when an exception happens after you would have otherwise `new`ed something.

Comment: "I made sure I 'new' all sections of memory I am returning.. etc etc.. "  I am a bit puzzled why you think it is good to "new" everything. You should do the opposite: Make sure you dont `new` anything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, it i a goo idea to start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up in small stages. Here you've written a lot of code at once, and it doesn't work. And you haven't given us enough to reproduce the error, even if we find *some* bugs, we can't be sure we've found *all* of them.

Comment: You're deleting things inside of `for` loops that you are still accessing on the next iteration.

Comment: Obviously, your `delete` do not match you `new`. You do a single `new[]` and multiple `delete[]`. Also, you never allocate memory for pointers inside your array. When deleting, you delete the whole array multiple times (and not each items followed by the array). For me, it seems that you have many useless variables. You don't make guess with memory and hope it works. If it's not an homework for learning memory allocation and pointers to pointers, better to use a design based on STL instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stay away from new/delete for as long as possible and I'd also move the functions operating on your structs *into* the structs or at least make them friend functions. Use a standard container (like std::vector) for storage. I replaced your functions for reading and displaying the objects with stream operators to make it easier to read/write using standard streams. This is supposed to read files in the format you specified and then stream the created objects to std::cout with the same format as you had in the original files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

class Song {
    std::string m_title;
    std::string m_length;
public:
    Song() : m_title(), m_length() {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Song&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Song&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Song& song) {
    os << song.m_length << "," << song.m_title;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Song& song) {
    std::string tmp;
    std::getline(is, tmp);
    std::string::size_type comma = tmp.find(",");
    if(comma != std::string::npos) {
        std::copy(tmp.cbegin(), tmp.cbegin()+comma, std::inserter(song.m_length, song.m_length.end()));
        std::copy(tmp.cbegin()+comma+1, tmp.cend(), std::inserter(song.m_title, song.m_title.end()));
    }
    return is;
}

class CD {
    std::string m_artist;
    std::string m_title;
    int m_year;
    int m_rate;
    std::vector<Song> m_songs;
public:
    CD() :
        m_artist(),
        m_title(),
        m_year(),
        m_rate(),
        m_songs()
    {}
    size_t size() { return m_songs.size(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const CD&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, CD&);    
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CD& cd) {
    os << cd.m_title << "\n" << cd.m_artist << "\n" << cd.m_year << "\n"
       << cd.m_rate << "\n" << cd.m_songs.size() << "\n";
    for(const Song& song : cd.m_songs) {
        os << song << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CD& cd) {
    int no_songs;
    std::getline(is, cd.m_title);
    std::getline(is, cd.m_artist);
    is >> cd.m_year;
    is >> cd.m_rate;
    is >> no_songs;
    is.ignore(); // discard rest of line
    cd.m_songs.reserve(no_songs);
    while(no_songs--) {
        Song a_song;
        is >> a_song;
        cd.m_songs.emplace_back(std::move(a_song));
    }
    return is;
}

class CDs {
    std::vector<CD> m_cds;
public:
    CDs() : m_cds() {}
    CDs(const std::string& Filename) :
        m_cds()
    {
        std::fstream cdfile(Filename);
        cdfile >> *this;
    }
    size_t size() { return m_cds.size(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const CDs&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, CDs&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CDs& cds) {
    for(const CD& cd : cds.m_cds) os << cd;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CDs& cds) {
    while( !is.eof() ) {
        CD a_cd;
        is >> a_cd;
        if( !is.eof() ) cds.m_cds.emplace_back(a_cd);
    }
    return is;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    CDs cds;
    for(const std::string& file : args) {
        std::fstream fs(file);
        fs >> cds;
    }
    std::cerr << "Number of CDs: " << cds.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << cds;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am unable to use vectors (our teacher hates vectors with a passion) and different prototypes and structs (given by assignment) then what is given..

Comment: Given those constraints this could just as well be made into a pure C program. I wonder why the teacher dislikes std::vector so much but still wants you to use std::string? They are not _that_ different.

Comment: Wait, a C++ teacher who "hates vectors with a passion"? What the fudge?

Comment: A "C++" teacher telling you to use `new[]` over `std::vector` is not teaching you C++, but "C that has to be passed to a C++ compiler"